# Grouping objects in Objective-C

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grouping

This may be a silly question, but I'm not all too experienced with iPhone development.

Lets say I have 5 labels, l1, l2, etc,. I want to be able to, lets say, change the font size of l1 or the color of l2 independently, which is easy. But I also want to be able to treat them as a group, lets say hide all of them at once, without having to go through [l1 setHidden:true], [l2 setHidden: true], etc,.

Is there any way of 'grouping' these items together, maybe in a for loop or an array or something that I am unaware of?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you answered your question already. an array is perfect for this sort of thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment from Daniel said, you can do this with an NSArray.

Example (untested, just from my mind - should work):

```
// Somewhere in your init method - assuming you have three labels
NSArray *labelArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: l1, l2, l3, nil];

// Somewhere in your code
- (void) hideAllLabels
{
  for (UILabel *label in labelArray)
  { 
    [label setHidden:TRUE];
  }
}
```

Comment: Per Apple, you shouldn't use `TRUE` and `FALSE` for `BOOL` values, but rather `YES` and `NO`

Comment: You can also automatically have these items added to an array using an `IBOutletCollection`

Comment: @Mike Z, TRUE and FALSE and YES and NO are completely interchangeable. There is no difference whatsoever between them, and which you use is personal preference. What makes you think TRUE and FALSE should not be used?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this is to use an IBOutletCollection. That's a new link like an outlet, only when you add views to an outlet collection, the system sets up an array of those objects, and as you add items to the collection, they are automatically added to the array. It's very cool.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way that they are already grouped.
If you make a call to the superview for the items inside it, it returns an array of those items. If you need to determine specific items within that list you can call for the class or you can assign a tag and detect that in your iteration.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [myView subviews];
for (UIView *thing in itemArray) {
  if (thing.tag == 100) {
    [thing setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
  }
}
```